# Adding HTML tags in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables, concatenation

Hi I have a simple question.
Why is this not working?

```
let plus = "+" + '<h1>'+"This is a heading"+'</h1>';
```

I am getting this as output:

```
+<h1>This is a heading</h1>
```

Please see: https://www.screencast.com/t/3ljKFFMa, here is what I want to have with the + Done. So I want to add the + and Done text as a variable.

Thank you explaining.
E.

Comment: how did you use plus variable?

Comment: You have `"+"` in your code.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: It's good practice to use the same quote style unless you need to change it for escaping purposes. Helps readability as well.

Comment: That's the expected output. Anything in single or double quotes, except escaped quotes, is a separate String. `+` concatenates Strings... or does Math.

Comment: This is the expected output, I am able to get the one and the text, but I want to add the "+<h1>Sometext</h1>" behind it, and I want to do it as a variable, or do I need to make a div for it. screencast.com/t/3ljKFFMa  My html look now like this: `code`<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Toets hier je taak">

<button id="myBtn">Click here</button>
<button id="btnReset">Reset</button>`code`

Answer (score 1):

As noted - you have the plus in the code and the browser is rendering it as a string amnd the rest of the h1 is then a string as well - not a html element of `<h1>`. If I understand your needs - you are trying to make a string and then have that rendered.

That way you can create the elements dynamically, add icons and other html elements and then add it into the DOM using innerHTML().

```js
let headingStr = '';

headingStr += '<h1>';
  headingStr += '<span class="icon">~</span>';
  headingStr += 'This is a heading';
  headingStr += '<span class="icon">*</span>';
headingStr += '</h1>';

document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = headingStr;
```

```css
#container {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: green;
  margin: 0;
 }
 
.icon {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: No this is not what I meant. I am actualy trying get this var node = document.createTextNode(taak + "+ <h1>some text</h1>"); so the plus is just a string. please see here: screencast.com/t/3ljKFFMa so dont want to add it in a div, as I have already in a div. Does this make sense?